# How to match the values of 1 table to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two tables, 1 with a list of list of Students & Subjects, and a second table with subjects as Header & student as Rows.

I need to highlight the corresponding cell where student & subject matches.
Please see the screenshot below.
Table-1 is in one Excel named Book-1 & Table-2 is in another Excel Book-2.
I tried to use the formula

=IF(SUMPRODUCT((Book-1.xlsx!$A$2:$A$35325=$B2)*(Book-2.xlsx!$B$2:$B$35325=C$1))=1,"Yes","")

But it is not working.

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: The workbook name must be in square brackets.  See my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Table 1 is in A1:B7:

If you just want to highlight the cells, use Conditional Formatting with this formula:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$D2)*($B$2:$B$7=E$1))
```

Or if you want to indicate the matches with "Yes", use this one:

```
 =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$D2)*($B$2:$B$7=E$1))=1,"Yes","")
```

Here is the result using both:

[image]

Comment: The count of the table may increase it is dynamic so can I remove the $ from the 2 & 7 in formula. If the first table is another excel named Book1 can I  refer it to there

Comment: Yes, you can reference the entire columns A & B in another workbook like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(([Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A=$D2)*([Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:$B=E$1))`.  Change the sheet name as necessary.  Amazingly, this even works when the other workbook is closed, at least in Mac Excel 2011.